# Fitting large table to single page

Tags: tables, formatting, longtable, fontsize, tabularx

I am trying to ensure that the below table fits into one page. I am fine if the font is smaller. I have already tried changing the font, but it didn't work well. Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[final,3p,times,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\small \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\captionsetup{font=large} 
  \caption{Description}
  {\footnotesize  This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports. Standard errors are reported in parantheses. * indicates significance at the 10\% level, ** at the 5\% level, and *** at the 1\% level. }\smallskip

\centering  
\begin{tabular}{@{}lcccccc@{}} 
\toprule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{Dependent Variable: Log(Price)}\\
\cmidrule{2-7}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{City-State Level} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{State Level}\\
\cmidrule(r){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) \\
\midrule
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
Single  & 0.195*** & 0.219*** & 0.149*** & 0.324*** & 0.313*** & 0.196*** \\
 & (0.0464) & (0.0395) & (0.0385) & (0.0452) & (0.0408) & (0.0370) \\ \addlinespace
Employed & 0.222*** & 0.231*** & 0.156*** & 0.365*** & 0.359*** & 0.251*** \\
 & (0.0249) & (0.0249) & (0.0200) & (0.0317) & (0.0315) & (0.0232) \\ \addlinespace
1 Place &  &  & 0.0551*** &  &  & 0.0628*** \\
 &  &  & (0.00606) &  &  & (0.00791) \\ \addlinespace
2 Place &  &  & 0.0382*** &  &  & 0.0554*** \\
 &  &  & (0.00760) &  &  & (0.0106) \\ \addlinespace
3 Place &  &  & 0.0266*** &  &  & 0.0428*** \\
 &  &  & (0.00900) &  &  & (0.0124) \\ \addlinespace
4 Place &  &  & 0.00827 &  &  & 0.0269* \\
 &  &  & (0.0112) &  &  & (0.0145) \\ \addlinespace
5 Place &  &  & -0.00981 &  &  & 0.0108 \\
 &  &  & (0.0126) &  &  & (0.0169) \\ \addlinespace
6 Place &  &  & -0.0268 &  &  & -0.00126 \\
 &  &  & (0.0177) &  &  & (0.0217) \\ \addlinespace
7 Place &  &  & -0.0277 &  &  & -0.0141 \\
 &  &  & (0.0194) &  &  & (0.0271) \\ \addlinespace
8 Place &  &  & 0.00274 &  &  & 0.0245 \\
 &  &  & (0.0248) &  &  & (0.0363) \\ \addlinespace
9 Place &  &  & -0.0102 &  &  & 0.0125 \\
 &  &  & (0.0448) &  &  & (0.0530) \\ \addlinespace
10 Place &  &  & -0.00944 &  &  & 0.00733 \\
 &  &  & (0.0445) &  &  & (0.0875) \\ \addlinespace
11 Place &  &  & 0.0234 &  &  & 0.0674 \\
 &  &  & (0.0359) &  &  & (0.0653) \\ \addlinespace
New Indicator &  &  & -0.122*** &  &  & -0.153*** \\
 &  &  & (0.00938) &  &  & (0.0136) \\ \addlinespace
Other Indicator &  &  & -0.0563*** &  &  & -0.0966*** \\
 &  &  & (0.00752) &  &  & (0.0101) \\ \addlinespace
Fraction of Profit  &  &  & 0.171*** &  &  & 0.230*** \\
All, City-Level &  &  & (0.0166) &  &  & (0.0193) \\ \addlinespace
Fraction of of Profit  &  &  & 0.107*** &  &  &  \\
All &  &  & (0.0139) &  &  &  \\ \addlinespace
Log(Population) &  &  & 0.304*** &  &  & 0.342*** \\
 &  &  & (0.105) &  &  & (0.122) \\ \addlinespace
Log(GDP per capita) &  &  & 0.365*** &  &  & 0.306*** \\
 &  &  & (0.0991) &  &  & (0.106) \\ \addlinespace
     \hline
Log(GDP per capita) $\times$ Year-Quarter FE &\ & X & X & & X & X \\  \addlinespace 
Year-Month FE & X& X& X& X& X& X\\ \addlinespace
City-State FE &\ X & X& X& & & \\ \addlinespace
State FE &\ & & & X& X& X \\ \addlinespace
    \hline

 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \addlinespace
Observations & 1,237,878 & 1,237,878 & 1,209,791 & 262,534 & 262,534 & 255,173 \\
R-squared & 0.821 & 0.826 & 0.837 & 0.852 & 0.861 & 0.877 \\
Number of City-State pairs & 46510 & 46510 & 45244 &  &  &  \\
Number of States &  &  &  & 7190 & 7190 & 6911\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}



\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: I have to give credit to @leandriis who was super helpful with the previous posts regarding this table.

Comment: With `\tiny` instead of `\small` it fits the page, but are you sure to have it on one page only?

Comment: Thanks @CarLaTeX . That makes the table extremely small, that's true. Is there a way to break it down into two pages where it continues?

Comment: @CarLaTeX, I have seen some tables were some parts of it move to the next page. So that would also be an alternative solution.

Comment: I'll post an answer with a `longtable` (if someone else doesn't do it before me)

Comment: Thanks @CarLaTeX that would be awesome. I look forward to your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mico was quicker than me, however, this is my solution:

```
\documentclass[final,3p,times,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=large} 
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\raggedright}m{#1}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{@{}M{8em}cccccc@{}}
  \caption{Description}\\[-1.5ex]
  \multicolumn{7}{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}{\footnotesize  This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports. Standard errors are reported in parantheses. * indicates significance at the 10\% level, ** at the 5\% level, and *** at the 1\% level. }
 \\[8ex]
\toprule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{Dependent Variable: Log(Price)}\\
\cmidrule{2-7}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{City-State Level} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{State Level}\\
\cmidrule(r){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{7}{@{}l@{}}{continues from the previous page}\\
\midrule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{Dependent Variable: Log(Price)}\\
\cmidrule{2-7}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{City-State Level} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{State Level}\\
\cmidrule(r){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) \\
 \midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{7}{@{}r@{}}{continues on the next page}
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
Single  & 0.195*** & 0.219*** & 0.149*** & 0.324*** & 0.313*** & 0.196*** \\
 & (0.0464) & (0.0395) & (0.0385) & (0.0452) & (0.0408) & (0.0370) \\ \addlinespace
Employed & 0.222*** & 0.231*** & 0.156*** & 0.365*** & 0.359*** & 0.251*** \\
 & (0.0249) & (0.0249) & (0.0200) & (0.0317) & (0.0315) & (0.0232) \\ \addlinespace
1 Place &  &  & 0.0551*** &  &  & 0.0628*** \\
 &  &  & (0.00606) &  &  & (0.00791) \\ \addlinespace
2 Place &  &  & 0.0382*** &  &  & 0.0554*** \\
 &  &  & (0.00760) &  &  & (0.0106) \\ \addlinespace
3 Place &  &  & 0.0266*** &  &  & 0.0428*** \\
 &  &  & (0.00900) &  &  & (0.0124) \\ \addlinespace
4 Place &  &  & 0.00827 &  &  & 0.0269* \\
 &  &  & (0.0112) &  &  & (0.0145) \\ \addlinespace
5 Place &  &  & -0.00981 &  &  & 0.0108 \\
 &  &  & (0.0126) &  &  & (0.0169) \\ \addlinespace
6 Place &  &  & -0.0268 &  &  & -0.00126 \\
 &  &  & (0.0177) &  &  & (0.0217) \\ \addlinespace
7 Place &  &  & -0.0277 &  &  & -0.0141 \\
 &  &  & (0.0194) &  &  & (0.0271) \\ \addlinespace
8 Place &  &  & 0.00274 &  &  & 0.0245 \\
 &  &  & (0.0248) &  &  & (0.0363) \\ \addlinespace
9 Place &  &  & -0.0102 &  &  & 0.0125 \\
 &  &  & (0.0448) &  &  & (0.0530) \\ \addlinespace
10 Place &  &  & -0.00944 &  &  & 0.00733 \\
 &  &  & (0.0445) &  &  & (0.0875) \\ \addlinespace
11 Place &  &  & 0.0234 &  &  & 0.0674 \\
 &  &  & (0.0359) &  &  & (0.0653) \\
New Indicator &  &  & -0.122*** &  &  & -0.153*** \\
 &  &  & (0.00938) &  &  & (0.0136) \\ \addlinespace
Other Indicator &  &  & -0.0563*** &  &  & -0.0966*** \\
 &  &  & (0.00752) &  &  & (0.0101) \\ \addlinespace
Fraction of Profit  &  &  & 0.171*** &  &  & 0.230*** \\
All, City-Level &  &  & (0.0166) &  &  & (0.0193) \\ \addlinespace
Fraction of of Profit  &  &  & 0.107*** &  &  &  \\
All &  &  & (0.0139) &  &  &  \\ \addlinespace
Log(Population) &  &  & 0.304*** &  &  & 0.342*** \\
 &  &  & (0.105) &  &  & (0.122) \\ \addlinespace
Log(GDP per capita) &  &  & 0.365*** &  &  & 0.306*** \\
 &  &  & (0.0991) &  &  & (0.106) \\ \addlinespace
\midrule
Log(GDP per capita) $\times$ Year-Quarter FE & & X & X & & X & X \\  \addlinespace 
Year-Month FE & X& X& X& X& X& X\\ \addlinespace
City-State FE &\ X & X& X& & & \\ \addlinespace
State FE &\ & & & X& X& X \\ \addlinespace
\midrule
Observations & 1,237,878 & 1,237,878 & 1,209,791 & 262,534 & 262,534 & 255,173 \\
R-squared & 0.821 & 0.826 & 0.837 & 0.852 & 0.861 & 0.877 \\
Number of City-State pairs & 46510 & 46510 & 45244 &  &  &  \\
Number of States &  &  &  & 7190 & 7190 & 6911\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, @CarLaTeX. This is super helpful. Is there any way to define the length of the first column as in Mico's answer? I like that fact that in your answer the Table description is below the Table title. However, the first column length doesn't seem to be changeable..

PS: I must note that one of the variables has a bit of a longer name (i.e., "Share of People from Europe Moved Permanently, State-Level"), so specifying the length would be super helpful.

Comment: @Job See my renewed answer, you can set any width you like with `M{...}`, but if you set a width > 8em you have to use smaller font size, otherwise you got an `Overfull \hbox`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This does the trick. Your code does exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: @Job You're welcome. You're very nice. Thank you for accepting my answer.

Comment: your help honestly saved a lot of time! The fact that your code was super flexible helped me so much. Thanks again for taking your time to help out. I really appreciated it!!

Answer (score 3):

Currently, your table is both too wide and too tall for the page.

- Unless you're willing to switch to an extremely small font size (which I would not recommend!), you need to enable a page break somewhere in the table. Since `table` and `tabular` environments cannot be broken across pages, I suggest you switch to a `longtable` environment.
- Moreover, in order to get the table to fit horizontally, I suggest you use a (modified form of the) `p` column type instead of `c` or `l` for the first column. Once you make this adjustment, it's no longer necessary to switch to `\small` for the entire table.
- In addition, I wouldn't use the `c` column type for the six data columns: Since much of the data consists of numbers, it would seem very important to align them on their respective decimal markers. Load the `dcolumn` package and use its `D` column type to achieve this type of alignment.
- I would also do away with the `\addlinespace` directives: They don't seem to be all that necessary or helpful, visually/aesthetically speaking.

The following screenshot shows just the first few lines of the table. (Note that I've taken the explanatory paragraph out of the `longtable` material.) Keep in mind that it's often necessary to compile a `longtable` two or three times before it looks right.

[image]

```
\documentclass[final,3p,times,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{caption,booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable,ragged2e,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hangindent1em}p{\mylen}}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % useful shorthand macro
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{Fraction of Profit All,} % width of header column
\begin{document}

The following table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports. Standard errors are reported in parantheses.

\begingroup % localize scope of the next few instructions
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip,font=normalsize} 
\begin{longtable}{@{} L{\mylen} *{6}{d{2.6}} @{}}
\caption{Description}\\

\multicolumn{7}{@{}l}{\footnotesize * indicates significance at the 10\% level, ** at the 5\% level, and *** at the 1\% level.} \\[1ex]

\toprule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{Dependent Variable: Log(Price)}\\
\cmidrule(l){2-7}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{City-State Level} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{State Level}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
 & \mc{(1)} & \mc{(2)} & \mc{(3)} & \mc{(4)} & \mc{(5)} & \mc{(6)} \\
\midrule  
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{7}{@{}l}{\footnotesize Table \thetable, cont'd}\\[1ex]
\toprule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{Dependent Variable: Log(Price)}\\
\cmidrule(l){2-7}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{City-State Level} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{State Level}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
 & \mc{(1)} & \mc{(2)} & \mc{(3)} & \mc{(4)} & \mc{(5)} & \mc{(6)} \\
\midrule  
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{7}{r@{}}{\footnotesize Cont'd on following page}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

Single  & 0.195^{***}& 0.219^{***}& 0.149^{***}& 0.324^{***}& 0.313^{***}& 0.196^{***}\\
 & (0.0464) & (0.0395) & (0.0385) & (0.0452) & (0.0408) & (0.0370) \\ %\addlinespace
Employed & 0.222^{***}& 0.231^{***}& 0.156^{***}& 0.365^{***}& 0.359^{***}& 0.251^{***}\\
 & (0.0249) & (0.0249) & (0.0200) & (0.0317) & (0.0315) & (0.0232) \\ %\addlinespace
1 Place &  &  & 0.0551^{***}&  &  & 0.0628^{***}\\
 &  &  & (0.00606) &  &  & (0.00791) \\ %\addlinespace
2 Place &  &  & 0.0382^{***}&  &  & 0.0554^{***}\\
 &  &  & (0.00760) &  &  & (0.0106) \\ %\addlinespace
3 Place &  &  & 0.0266^{***}&  &  & 0.0428^{***}\\
 &  &  & (0.00900) &  &  & (0.0124) \\ %\addlinespace
4 Place &  &  & 0.00827 &  &  & 0.0269* \\
 &  &  & (0.0112) &  &  & (0.0145) \\ %\addlinespace
5 Place &  &  & -0.00981 &  &  & 0.0108 \\
 &  &  & (0.0126) &  &  & (0.0169) \\ %\addlinespace
6 Place &  &  & -0.0268 &  &  & -0.00126 \\
 &  &  & (0.0177) &  &  & (0.0217) \\ %\addlinespace
7 Place &  &  & -0.0277 &  &  & -0.0141 \\
 &  &  & (0.0194) &  &  & (0.0271) \\ %\addlinespace
8 Place &  &  & 0.00274 &  &  & 0.0245 \\
 &  &  & (0.0248) &  &  & (0.0363) \\ %\addlinespace
9 Place &  &  & -0.0102 &  &  & 0.0125 \\
 &  &  & (0.0448) &  &  & (0.0530) \\ %\addlinespace
10 Place &  &  & -0.00944 &  &  & 0.00733 \\
 &  &  & (0.0445) &  &  & (0.0875) \\ %\addlinespace
11 Place &  &  & 0.0234 &  &  & 0.0674 \\
 &  &  & (0.0359) &  &  & (0.0653) \\ %\addlinespace
New Indicator &  &  & -0.122^{***}&  &  & -0.153^{***}\\
 &  &  & (0.00938) &  &  & (0.0136) \\ %\addlinespace
Other Indicator &  &  & -0.0563^{***}&  &  & -0.0966^{***}\\
 &  &  & (0.00752) &  &  & (0.0101) \\ %\addlinespace
Fraction of Profit All,  &  &  & 0.171^{***}&  &  & 0.230^{***}\\
\quad City-Level &  &  & (0.0166) &  &  & (0.0193) \\ %\addlinespace
Fraction of Profit All  &  &  & 0.107^{***}&  &  &  \\
    &  &  & (0.0139) &  &  &  \\ %\addlinespace
Log(Population) &  &  & 0.304^{***}&  &  & 0.342^{***}\\
 &  &  & (0.105) &  &  & (0.122) \\ %\addlinespace
Log(GDP per capita) &  &  & 0.365^{***}&  &  & 0.306^{***}\\
 &  &  & (0.0991) &  &  & (0.106) \\ %\addlinespace
\midrule
Log(GDP per capita) $\times$ Year-Quarter~FE & & \mc{X} & \mc{X} & & \mc{X} & \mc{X} \\  %\addlinespace 
Year-Month FE & \mc{X}& \mc{X}& \mc{X}& \mc{X}& \mc{X}& \mc{X}\\ %\addlinespace
City-State FE & \mc{X} & \mc{X} & \mc{X} & & & \\ %\addlinespace
State FE & & & & \mc{X}& \mc{X}& \mc{X} \\ %\addlinespace
\midrule
Observations & \mc{1,237,878} & \mc{1,237,878} & \mc{1,209,791} & \mc{262,534} & \mc{262,534} & \mc{255,173} \\
R-squared & 0.821 & 0.826 & 0.837 & 0.852 & 0.861 & 0.877 \\
Number of City-State pairs & \mc{46510} & \mc{46510} & \mc{45244} &  &  &  \\
Number of States &  &  &  & \mc{7190} & \mc{7190} & \mc{6911}\\ 

\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's a great answer, @Mico. Is there any way to add the table description (The following table report" part) below "Table 1: Description"?

Comment: I assume adding this part (which is from @CarLaTeX) would solve the issue: 

  \multicolumn{7}{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}{\footnotesize  This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports. Standard errors are reported in parantheses. * indicates significance at the 10\% level, ** at the 5\% level, and *** at the 1\% level. } \\

Comment: @Job - A `longtable`, unlike a `table`, does not "float" (in the TeX-specific sense of the word). Thus, in my answer, the legend will always be right before the tabular material. Whether one places this legend *inside* or *immediately before* the `longtable` is, to me, mostly a matter of aesthetics. To me, placing the legend outside (but immediately before) the `longtable` signals to readers of my papers: "Wake up, wake up! Hello! You're about to hit a tabular section of the text. Here's what this coming tabular section is all about." I realize that you may or may not agree with this view.

Comment: @Job - The `longtable` will, in general, be less wide than `\textwidth`. If you place the legend *inside* the longtable, via the `\multicolumn{7}{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}{\footnotesize ...}` device, you may create a weird-looking disparity in widths of the legend paragraph and the subsequent tabular material. It is exactly because I wanted to avoid creating such a visual disparity that I decided to take the legend out of the `longtable` and place it right before the tabular material. (Obviously, the width of a plain-text paragraph is `\textwidth`.)

Comment: Thanks so much, @Mico. I am replicating a paper and want to follow exactly their formatting. Otherwise your suggestion is certainly well taken. Thanks so much for all of your help!

Answer (score 2):

I've modified `arraystretch` and the `fontsize`, please refer the below:

```
\documentclass[final,3p,times,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\captionsetup{font=large} 
  \caption{Description}
  {\footnotesize  This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports This table reports. Standard errors are reported in parantheses. * indicates significance at the 10\% level, ** at the 5\% level, and *** at the 1\% level. }\smallskip
\centering\scriptsize%
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}%
\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.75}%
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep\fill}lcccccc@{\extracolsep\fill}} 
\toprule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{Dependent Variable: Log(Price)}\\
\cmidrule{2-7}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{City-State Level} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{State Level}\\
\cmidrule(r){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) \\
\midrule
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
Single  & 0.195*** & 0.219*** & 0.149*** & 0.324*** & 0.313*** & 0.196*** \\
 & (0.0464) & (0.0395) & (0.0385) & (0.0452) & (0.0408) & (0.0370) \\ \addlinespace
Employed & 0.222*** & 0.231*** & 0.156*** & 0.365*** & 0.359*** & 0.251*** \\
 & (0.0249) & (0.0249) & (0.0200) & (0.0317) & (0.0315) & (0.0232) \\ \addlinespace
1 Place &  &  & 0.0551*** &  &  & 0.0628*** \\
 &  &  & (0.00606) &  &  & (0.00791) \\ \addlinespace
2 Place &  &  & 0.0382*** &  &  & 0.0554*** \\
 &  &  & (0.00760) &  &  & (0.0106) \\ \addlinespace
3 Place &  &  & 0.0266*** &  &  & 0.0428*** \\
 &  &  & (0.00900) &  &  & (0.0124) \\ \addlinespace
4 Place &  &  & 0.00827 &  &  & 0.0269* \\
 &  &  & (0.0112) &  &  & (0.0145) \\ \addlinespace
5 Place &  &  & -0.00981 &  &  & 0.0108 \\
 &  &  & (0.0126) &  &  & (0.0169) \\ \addlinespace
6 Place &  &  & -0.0268 &  &  & -0.00126 \\
 &  &  & (0.0177) &  &  & (0.0217) \\ \addlinespace
7 Place &  &  & -0.0277 &  &  & -0.0141 \\
 &  &  & (0.0194) &  &  & (0.0271) \\ \addlinespace
8 Place &  &  & 0.00274 &  &  & 0.0245 \\
 &  &  & (0.0248) &  &  & (0.0363) \\ \addlinespace
9 Place &  &  & -0.0102 &  &  & 0.0125 \\
 &  &  & (0.0448) &  &  & (0.0530) \\ \addlinespace
10 Place &  &  & -0.00944 &  &  & 0.00733 \\
 &  &  & (0.0445) &  &  & (0.0875) \\ \addlinespace
11 Place &  &  & 0.0234 &  &  & 0.0674 \\
 &  &  & (0.0359) &  &  & (0.0653) \\ \addlinespace
New Indicator &  &  & -0.122*** &  &  & -0.153*** \\
 &  &  & (0.00938) &  &  & (0.0136) \\ \addlinespace
Other Indicator &  &  & -0.0563*** &  &  & -0.0966*** \\
 &  &  & (0.00752) &  &  & (0.0101) \\ \addlinespace
Fraction of Profit  &  &  & 0.171*** &  &  & 0.230*** \\
All, City-Level &  &  & (0.0166) &  &  & (0.0193) \\ \addlinespace
Fraction of of Profit  &  &  & 0.107*** &  &  &  \\
All &  &  & (0.0139) &  &  &  \\ \addlinespace
Log(Population) &  &  & 0.304*** &  &  & 0.342*** \\
 &  &  & (0.105) &  &  & (0.122) \\ \addlinespace
Log(GDP per capita) &  &  & 0.365*** &  &  & 0.306*** \\
 &  &  & (0.0991) &  &  & (0.106) \\ \addlinespace
     \hline
Log(GDP per capita) $\times$ Year-Quarter FE &\ & X & X & & X & X \\  \addlinespace 
Year-Month FE & X& X& X& X& X& X\\ \addlinespace
City-State FE &\ X & X& X& & & \\ \addlinespace
State FE &\ & & & X& X& X \\ \addlinespace
    \hline

 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \addlinespace
Observations & 1,237,878 & 1,237,878 & 1,209,791 & 262,534 & 262,534 & 255,173 \\
R-squared & 0.821 & 0.826 & 0.837 & 0.852 & 0.861 & 0.877 \\
Number of City-State pairs & 46510 & 46510 & 45244 &  &  &  \\
Number of States &  &  &  & 7190 & 7190 & 6911\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}



\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks very much. The table looks a bit different now. There are many boxes (i.e., lines) that were not needed.

Comment: @Job Oops...Please remove the package `showframe` and then try....

Comment: I appreciate the effort to shoehorn the table into a single page. I must say, though, it looks odd to have a table with a `\large` caption, a `\footnotesize` legend, and a `\scriptsize` body.

Comment: @Mico I agreed, shall I correct this?

Comment: No. (Well, maybe switch the font size for the caption from `\large` to `\small` (or `\footnotesize`.) I would just point out explicitly which design choices you imposed. That way, readers can form their own opinions as to what may or may not work for their own tables.

Comment: @Mico Fine and I'll leave as is....

Comment: @MadyYuvi thanks for your kind reply. Mico and CarLaTeX made a great point that it would make more sense to just do a continuation of the table on the next page. I, however, greatly appreciate your answer as well! I am sure others will benefit from it, too.

Comment: @Job Both Mico and CarLaTeX are the superiors than me...I too agree their answer is better than what I suggested...no issues...